# How to create an field that only accepts other fields?

Tags: idris

I want to create a datatype with alternating constructors `Foo` and `Bar`. A valid member, for example, would be:

```
Foo (Bar (Foo (Bar End)))
```

But not:

```
Foo (Foo (Bar End))
```

Since the latter has two consecutive Foo's. What is the right way to express this in a single data declaration?

Comment: Is `Foo End` allowed?

Comment: @AntonTrunov no... could be, though... I'm just wondering what the general syntax for that is.

Comment: Added `Foo End` version into my answer.

Comment: I hate when multiple people give perfectly good answers, it feels as if I select an answer I'm saying the other is bad, and if I select no answer I'm saying I didn't like any.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that :) From my PoV you're not saying that other answer(s) is(are) bad, you're just saying that some explanation worked for you better. And that is highly individual.

Comment: Often the question is very objective so both explanations work the same, though, that is the case here, for example.

Answer (score 3):

With a single declaration, you need an indexed type:

```
data Foo : Bool -> Type where
  End : Foo True
  Bar : Foo True -> Foo False
  Foo : Foo False -> Foo True
```

This has the same inhabitants as the following two mutual types:

```
data FooTrue = End | Foo FooFalse
data FooFalse = Bar FooTrue
```

In general, a mutual family of `n` data types is representable with a single type family indexed by a type with `n` elements. The indexed representation has the advantage that it admits generic operations that are impossible with mutual types, since one may have transformations with types like `{b : Bool} -> Foo b -> Foo b` or `{b : Bool} -> Foo b -> Foo (not b)`. Infinite mutual families like length-indexed lists are also only possible with indexed types.

Comment: Interesting, so you necessarily need another datatype (Bool), right? So, the `∀ (A : *) . ∀ (B : *) . ∀ (foo : (A -> B)) . ∀ (bar : (B -> A)) . ∀ (end : B) . B` type, which includes terms of the shape I mentioned, like `(λ foo . λ bar . λ end . (foo (bar (foo (bar end))))`, doesn't have a direct representation as an Idris datatype, correct?

Comment: It has a representation, but it has type `Type 1` instead of `Type` which makes it not very useful. For any sort of usable Church encoding, we need `(∀ (A : *). t) : *`, i. e. an impredicative `*`. System F has impredicative `*`, but it doesn't have dependency and induction, Agda/Idris have induction but no impredicativity.

Comment: However, Coq does have an option called `-impredicative-set` which makes the first level of `Type` impredicative (and restricts some elimination into bigger types IIRC), which lets us Church encode as much as we like. It's disabled by default though because it's inconsistent with classical logic, and classical logic is usually more important in Coq than Church data.

Comment: Just double checking, what you said is that there exists a representation of terms of that form, using inductive datatypes, without depending on Bool, but that representation has type `Type 1`, correct? (I wasn't referring to the church-encoding itself, just used it as an example of the inductive type I had in mind.)

Comment: Well, I was referring specifically to the Church encoding. The inductive definition with two mutual types doesn't depend on `Bool` and is in `Type 0`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is using an indexed type:

```
data FooBarEnd : Nat -> Type where
  End : FooBarEnd 0
  Foo : FooBarEnd 1 -> FooBarEnd 0
  Bar : FooBarEnd 0 -> FooBarEnd 1
```

A couple tests:

```
test1 : FooBarEnd 0
test1 = Foo (Bar (Foo (Bar End)))

test2 : FooBarEnd 0
test2 = End

test3 : FooBarEnd 1
test3 = Bar End
```

`Foo (Foo (Bar End))` is not a valid term neither for `FooBarEnd 0`, nor `FooBarEnd 1`.

The downside of this approach is the necessity of using the indices `0` and `1`.
I'm not sure whether this is the kind of solution you are looking for.

---

If you decide to allow `Foo End` as a valid term, the definition can be  changed into this:

```
data FooBarEnd : Nat -> Type where
  End : FooBarEnd 1
  Foo : {auto prf : n `GTE` 1} -> FooBarEnd n -> FooBarEnd 0
  Bar : {auto prf : n `LTE` 1} -> FooBarEnd n -> FooBarEnd 2
```

Where `GTE` and `LTE` mean greater or equal and less or equal correspondingly.

The above allows `Foo End`, `Bar End`, etc., preserving your original restriction, and Idris is capable of inferring the implicit proof terms `prf` automatically.

More informally, the (unary) constructor `Foo` expects a value of types `FooBarEnd 1` or `FooBarEnd 2` as an argument, which means we are only allowed to build `Foo End` or `Foo (Bar ...)`, because we separated each of the constructors into their own "subtype", indexed by a natural number. And the constructor `Bar` expects either `End` (with index `1` <= 1) or `Foo` (with index `0` <= 1).